# Using AWK to filter a file based on the numerical value of a column (where the column number and numerical value are passed in from the command line)

Tags: text-processing, awk, variable

I have a file that is tab-delimited. I am trying to use AWK to filter the file such that the user can specify a column number and a number, and the script will return only the lines of the file (and the header) where the value in that specified column is greater than that number. For example, if I wanted column 3 and threshold of 0.28, I want to take the following file

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
...  ...  0.12 ...  ...
...  ...  0.323 ...  ...
...  ...  0.4123 ...  ...
...  ...  0.002 ...  ...
...  ...  0.896 ...  ...
```

and get

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
...  ...  0.323 ...  ...
...  ...  0.4123 ...  ...
...  ...  0.896 ...  ...
```

I have tried the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

#For testing

echo $1

echo $2

echo $3

awk -v col="$1" -v val="$2" '$col > $val' filename
```

When I try to run `bash script.sh 3 0.28 filename`, I get no rows of the file printed out. The only thing that appears is printing out 3, 0.28, and filename because of the echo commands.

However, if I change the script such that it says

```
awk -v col="$1" -v val="$2" '$col > 0.28' filename
```

I get the expected filtering behavior. I thought that maybe `$val` wasn't being interpreted as a number, so I tried

```
awk -v col="$1" -v val="$2" '$col > ($val + 0)' filename
```

This causes every row of the file to be printed out, which makes me think that it is being evaluated as TRUE. I'm new to AWK, so I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: `$val` refers to the `val`th *field* - you likely want `$col > val`

Comment: Oh, gosh, thank you so much. That fixed it.

Comment: and to get the header line too: `'(NR==1) || ($col > (val + 0))'`